# How to configure atom-beautify package to format with babel/jsx javascript files?

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor, babeljs, prettify

I searched for a package to auto-indent and beautify my React/babel code. I just tried [atom-beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) which seems to have good feeback on Atom.

But the result on an usual babel file is not good enough: "HTML tag" doesn't indent as wanted. Has anyone tried to use atom-beautify with babel?

Comment: Please feel free to create an Issue on the Atom-Beautify repository: https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/issues
By providing a `debug.md` Gist myself and others may be able to help you to get it working.

Comment: did you find a working solution?

Comment: Nope. I use VSCode instead that is most powerfull in formatting jsx :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atom beautify did not support jsx at that time. [it does now](https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/issues/974) :)

Answer (score 12):

I currently use the plugins language-babel, react, and autoclose-html to handle this for me with no issues.

https://atom.io/packages/autoclose-html

https://atom.io/packages/language-babel

https://atom.io/packages/react

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried language-babel but, correct me if I'm wrong, it auto-indents only jsx not local javascript in function & co.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't be certain on that. I just went in and played around with settings and it seems to have the options that you're looking for, and I've had no issues, all my javascript and react code is properly indented automatically. Sorry if this wasn't more help.

Comment: `react` and `language-babel` seem to be colliding with each other - I get a warning message about this.

Comment: I had this collision problem too. I'm using only `react` for now and it seems to help a lot

Comment: Same problem here, react and language-babel doesn´t work together. I used language-babel so far.

Answer (score 4):

I already faced the same problem and ended using [prettier-atom](https://atom.io/packages/prettier-atom) . It works really nice with HTML tags.

Answer (score 3):

I use Prettier (https://prettier.io/) to re-write my code into best practices, so all the team can write code as if only one person has written it all. Supports JSX, and recently, even TypeScript, CSS, SCSS, ..

Comment: I just started using Atom with the Nuclide package for JSX. Prettier works just fine!

Answer (score 1):

I use [miniprettier](https://atom.io/packages/miniprettier), it's listed on [Prettier official site](https://prettier.io/docs/en/editors.html) as a recommended package.

It's like prettier-atom but without all the dependencies. I love it! It works very well on JSX. I use atom-beautify for other filetypes (e.g. JSON, pure HTML, JS).

Comment: I like miniprettier, but there's no way to apply it on save .